# What is the cleanest way to translate 42010958 Milliseconds to Hours:Minutes:Seconds in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, time, milliseconds, qtime

The [QTime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html) Class offers me a bit of a pickle insofar as it does not allow me to set milliseconds above certain values, thus making an entry like this invalid.:

```
    QTime time;
    time.setHMS(0,0,0,42010958); // I normally use a variable
```

Considering that the range of milliseconds I'm dealing with is between about `1000` and `1000000000`, I'm not terribly keen on writing a tremendous amount of of integer conversion code to sanitise each entry, but I will do what I have to do.

What is the cleanest way to convert `42010958` Milliseconds into `Hours:Minutes:Seconds` in Qt?

Comment: `QTime time; time = time.addMSecs(42010958);` ?  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#addSecs

Comment: @Robᵩ You'd think so, but no. Same restrictions still apply.

Comment: If the question was not strictly about Qt I would try to make up something with http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Cleanest" is a matter of taste, but here's how I would do it:

```
int milliseconds = 42010958;
int seconds      = milliseconds / 1000;
milliseconds     = milliseconds % 1000;
int minutes      = seconds / 60; 
seconds          = seconds % 60;
int hours        = minutes / 60;
minutes          = minutes % 60;

QTime time;
time.setHMS(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Comment: Apart from that colon in there, this is a very clean and working solution. I'll give it a few minutes in case anyone knows of a function that makes this even cleaner. Otherwise I thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`QTime::fromMSecsSinceStartOfDay`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#fromMSecsSinceStartOfDay).

```
#include <QtCore>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QTime time = QTime::fromMSecsSinceStartOfDay(42010958);
    qDebug() << time.toString("hh:mm:ss:zzz");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The `QCoreApplication` instance is unnecessary, and in an example you can use a single `<QtCore>` include :)

Comment: @KubaOber Woops, I just used the console application template when I made the example.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the STL.

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto milliseconds = 42010958ms;
auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(milliseconds);
milliseconds -= seconds;
auto minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(seconds);
seconds -= minutes;
auto hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(minutes);
minutes -= hours;
```

Comment: +1 And add `#include "chrono_io.h" (https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/chrono_io.html)` if you want rock-solid debugging of your durations such as `std::cout << hours << '\n';`  That will confirm that not only is the run-time value of `hours` is correct, but the *compile-time* type of `hours` is _also_ correct. :-)

Comment: And people wonder why everyone looks outside of the standard library first. This kind of verboseness is rather sad in the design of a library meant for widespread reuse.